# I need to add a js file to be able to manipulate html

Tags: orocommerce

I need to be able to add a js file to be able to manipulate the html? I tried to add something similar to what is done in the assets.yml by loading the styles.css, but I did not have the expected result, and I do not understand how else I could do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do JavaScript coding inline, I would suggest making a separate file for it though, just like you do with a `.css` file. A `.js` file is called with a `<script>` tag instead of `<link>` in your HTML document.

**How to do it**

Make a new file called `main.js` inside your folder

Call it with the `<script>` tag in your HTML document, usually just before the closing `</body>` tag.

Make an element and manipulate it - this example is the `p` element that has the ID `#change`. One way to do it is with `document.querySelector`. You can do it with a classname as well if you prefer.
I'll let you do the rest.

```js
document.querySelector('#change').innerHTML =
```

```html
<p id="change">Change me</p>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new Quick Start Guide in a JavaScript tutorial that has the exact example you are asking for:
https://doc.oroinc.com/frontend/javascript/js-quick-start/